# How do I map Service, Port and Operation in SOAP WSDL to url?

Tags: soap, wsdl

Here is my [WSDL file](https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx?wsdl), which is definition of web service.

I know web service, and REST api, but just know the basic of SOAP. Every time I see a WSDL file, I can't help myself to map service and port to url. Is this the right way of thinking? or I should give up the idea of mapping service to URL at all?

If it is possible to map WSDL to REST url, how do I map it?

`<port>`/`<operation>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<wsdl:port>
<soap:address location="http://test.developer.intuit.com:83/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx">
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="TroubleshootWebServiceFSSoap12" binding="tns:TroubleshootWebServiceFSSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://test.developer.intuit.com:83/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

If you see the `wsdl`, there are two URLs one is default and other is for SOAP1.2, and but both are same. So doesn't matter.

SOAP1.2, URL will be `http://test.developer.intuit.com:83/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx`

Operation names are `serverVersion`,`clientVersion`,`authenticate` etc.

URL doesn't change with Operation, it will remain same for all the operations.

Hope it answers both of your questions.

Comment: so all operation will use the same endpoint (URL), e.g.: "http://test.developer.intuit.com:83/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx" Then how do the server tell which operation is triggered? In HTTP Header? query string?  SOAP server is a HTTP server at first place, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Telling operation name will be SOAP XML's responsibility. As an example, `<?xml version="1.0"?><soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body>
  <m:GetPrice>
    <m:Item>Apples</m:Item>
  </m:GetPrice>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`, Here operation name is `GetPrice`. Use any standard SOAP liberary, you need no to deal with that headache, for e.g. axis2 in Java, zeep in python etc.